# How to Annotate Kubernetes Service Account with IAM Role using Terraform for AWS EKS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

"I am currently setting up an EBS CSI driver on AWS EKS using Terraform. However, I am experiencing an issue with attaching the necessary IAM role to the service account (`ebs-csi-controller-sa`) that is required for the driver.

Here is the Terraform configuration I am using to create the EBS CSI driver:

```
resource "aws_eks_addon" "aws-ebs-csi-driver" {
  cluster_name      = module.ep_eks.cluster_id
  addon_name        = "aws-ebs-csi-driver"
  addon_version     = "v1.18.0-eksbuild.1" 
  resolve_conflicts = "OVERWRITE"
}
```

I got a response from AWS support stating that the IAM role isn't being annotated to the `ebs-csi-controller-sa` service account. They suggested using `kubectl` commands to annotate the service account manually.

However, I want to manage everything through Terraform. Is there a way to use Terraform to annotate the service account with the IAM role?

If not, what is the recommended way to handle this kind of situation, where I need to annotate a service account with an IAM role for a resource managed by Terraform?

Any help would be appreciated!"

Comment: You should be able to that by using the Kubernetes provider and a corresponding resource: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/service_account_v1.